# How does React improves performance in re-render when state changes?

Tags: reactjs

I was going through the tutorial of React here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_components.htm

In this page, there is a example, where author says, how passing key prop in the component helps in improving performance in re-rendering. Can someone explain how?

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         data: 
         [
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"Foo",
               "age":"20"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "name":"Bar",
               "age":"30"
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "name":"Baz",
               "age":"40"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Header/>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  {this.state.data.map((person, i) => <TableRow key = {i} 
                     data = {person} />)}
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Header</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
class TableRow extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <tr>
            <td>{this.props.data.id}</td>
            <td>{this.props.data.name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.data.age}</td>
         </tr>
      );
   }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: `Notice that we are using key = {i} inside map() function. This will help React to update only the necessary elements instead of re-rendering the entire list when something changes. It is a huge performance boost for larger number of dynamically created elements.` per the linked article => keys, in this particular context, allow the react DOM to rerender only what has been updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that is my question. How does keys help in that? Is key some special prop which helps in that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `key` is a special prop/attribute in react. When mapping JSX react will actually complain if you do not specify keys, or have any duplicate keys.

[react keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

If the key is the same as the last render react won't re-render that piece. This is also one of the gotchas when devs use the index parameter of the `array::map` function as the key... if one of the elements *actually is* different, but has the same key as the previous render, react won't re-render it. You should ensure the keys you use are unique within your dataset.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in reading about how [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) functions in react. The linked article eventually discusses keys as a solution to the problem of react-dom rendering scaling to the order of O(n^3) where n is the number of elements in the dom.

> React supports a key attribute. When children have keys, React uses
> the key to match children in the original tree with children in then
> subsequent tree.

Keys allow the react-dom to not have to mutate the data in the dom. If the entire dom-tree is rebuilt, it is computationally less scalar. With keys, react can use a better algorithm:

> React implements a heuristic O(n) algorithm based on two assumptions:
>
> 1. Two elements of different types will produce different trees.
> 2. The developer can hint at which child elements may be stable across
>    different renders with a key prop.

If you read over the linked article, this should make a lot more sense.